# Reading messages from database in order

Tags: mysql

I am currently building a conversation style messaging system and need to assistance on the order of the messages being read from the database.

The database structure of message table in the database is as follows:

messageid | content | message_from | message_to | viewed | deleted | sent_date

I want to read the messages out in the order they are sent but not repeat the username if multiple messages are sent without a reply.

So if there were 3 message_from to the same message_to, they would be displayed and then any response would come after that. But as I said, if there were 3 messages from the same person without a response, I would display the username at first and then just content there after.

I have the following query which pulls out messages sent to the user.

```
SELECT f.username, t.username, m.content, m.sent_date FROM message m 
INNER JOIN user f ON f.userid = m.message_from
INNER JOIN user t ON t.userid = m.message_to
WHERE f.username = :username
```

I've tried my best to explain what I need, not sure how clear I have been!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make the decision on displaying the username in the display logic, rather than the database logic. (ie. in your HTML generation script)

To make sure the results are in the correct order, use `ORDER BY m.sent_date ASC` at the end of your SQL statement.

Comment: +1: It is a presentation issue, and the DBMS should not be forced into sorting out the presentation.

Comment: I'll use PHP to loop through and sort the username logic out but with the initial query, do I select if the message_from or message_to is equal to the current user and either field is equal to the user that the conversation is with? That's the only way to get messages that go both ways?

Comment: You might be overcomplicating things with those ```INNER JOIN```s! Would this work? ```SELECT DISTINCT * FROM messages WHERE message_from = :username OR message_to = :username ORDER BY sent_date ASC;``` (PDO-style query there)